# Rails Page Caching for XHR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, page-caching

How does Rails' `cahes_page` mechanism deal with Ajax/XHR requests?

An action typically responds differently based on `request.xhr?`, but the path is the same. So will Rails arrange for both versions to be cached?

Answer (score 0):

Please find this may be useful to you http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2005/10/6/ruby-on-rails-caching-part-2